# Foundation.js not working on pages with hash URI

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I've enabled `accordion` and `form-abide`, neither of them is doing anything when the page is in a hash URI. It works when I disable my client-side routing. I have `$(document).foundation();` in the bottom of my `<body>` already.

Here's the page and the hash URI in question: http://ingrower.apps.quantisan.com/#/production/A3

If I not use the `/#/` client-side routing, then things seem to work. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have any errors or warnings in your console? Also, check your network tab in the inspector, relative URLs to your scripts might be broken due to the `/#/`.

Comment: Looks like the problem is because I'm using client-side routing. When the DOM changes, Foundation isn't aware of the new content so the jquery selectors aren't picking up the events.

Answer (score 1):

Change `<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` to be `/js/app.js`. The page is trying to load your relative javascript at `/#/app.js` which obviously doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I explicitly called `$(document).foundation('reflow');` after each client-side page load. In particular, making use of ComponentDidUpdate ReactJs lifecycle. This works now.

Although loading foundation() for every DOM update is obviously an overkill. I'm hoping there'd be a more elegant solution out there...